# How to use TF-IDF vector (sparse matrix) with numerical features?

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, tf-idf

I found [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44383/classification-how-to-handle-reviews-long-english-words-in-feature-set-with-all) that mentions using toarray() on the tf-idf sparse matrix and then making a dataframe from it and concatenating with the other dataframe.

However, using Google Colab the session crashes (I believe memory issue). Is there a workaround for this?

I want to use numerical features from LIWC (Linguistic Inquiry Word Count) categories as well as TF-IDF to build a classification model using logistic regression.

Apologies if this question was not formatted correctly, it's one of my first questions.

Answer (score 0):

What package are you using? If you are using `scikit-learn`, it sounds like you are looking for [FeatureUnion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) - there is an example on that page.